# Nuevo char en c++ me da largo equivocado

Tags: c++

La pregunta es porque cuando hago

```
char *ic( char *p ) {
  int largo = strlen( p );
  char *retorno = new char[largo]( )
}
```

Siendo el largo del char p = 4, me crea retorno de largo 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy suponiendo que al momento de pasarle el puntero char a tu funcion estas declarando un arreglo y no le terminaste por especificar el caracter nulo ejemplo

```
int main()
{
    char arr[]={'a','b','c','d'};
    ic(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Por lo tanto la funcion strlen no calcula adecuadamente el tamano del puntero a char porque no encuentra el caracter nulo que indica el fin de la cadena.

La forma de corregirlo es obviamente agregandole el caracter de nulo

```
 char arr[]={'a','b','c','d','\0'};
```